# Access url parameter in included file?

Tags: php, include

It seems like the code of an included file can't access url parameter? Is there a way round this?

Working code

index.php

```
if((isset($_GET["param"]))){
    $_SESSION['test'] = $_GET["param"];
} else { 
    unset($_SESSION['test']);   
}

include("temp.php");
```

temp.php

```
echo $_SESSION['test'];
```

Not working

index.php

```
include("temp.php");
```

temp.php

```
if((isset($_GET["param"]))){
        $_SESSION['test'] = $_GET["param"];
    } else { 
        unset($_SESSION['test']);   
    }
    echo $_SESSION['test'];
```

Comment: So where is your session_start();

Comment: If you inspect your $_GET using something like var_dump($_GET) inside your temp.php you should see whats sent in the URL. You can do the same on your $_SESSION and see what is what... Don't rely soley on what you see or don't see with echo $_SESSION['test']

Comment: whenever you work on session, you must start_session() so you must add it as first line to the file (temp.php)

Comment: Including a file is almost identical to just substituting the code of the file into the first file. There's no problem with accessing variables in the include file.